# How to use Laravel Cashier subscriptions through an eloquent relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-cashier

The [Cashier documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing) is pretty clear on how to create a subscription for a user but does not explain very well how we can extend it.

What I want to do is pretty much like Github teams. I have organizations (or teams) and want to bill monthly one designated user in the organization.

So I have a `belongsToMany` relationship between my organization and its users and the organization has a `payer_id` field which specifies what user should take care of the organization’s monthly payment. I don't think this is wrong, but tell me if that part should be rethought.

The next part is the one I don't get. What I thought was using the `Billable` train on my user model, but having a `newSubscription()` method on my organization model that would then pass the variables to the user? But that feels wrong.

This [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/pull/337) seems to bring a solution, but I still don't get where I should go from here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I a understood, cashier does not (yet) provide this kind of flexibility. To me (this is my very personal opinion) cashier is a kind of happy-case implementation. If you need just a simple subscription on your user model, drop it in and it will work fine out of the box.

But if you need something more individualized than that, I would prefer to skip the cashier layer and work directly with the payment providers sdk. Since you are probably using stripe, have a look at their [docs](https://stripe.com/docs) and their [php sdk](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php), it works like a charm. And it gives you the flexibility to implement the solution which fits your requirements.

Again, just my 2 cents. Hope this input helps you.